# Updating records in a cursor for each loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update the teacher_id of all the student records(records from 1st 
    select statement) with new teacher_id from 2nd select statement. I am using 
    the below code, unfortunately it doesn't work from me. 
    can anyone tell me where it is breaking. Thanks

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_teacher IS

    u_id   NUMBER(6);
    CURSOR teacher_exist IS SELECT
        st.student_id,
        st.teacher_id,
        st.college_id,
        rd.role_name
                            FROM
        student_info st, 
        teacher p,
        teacher_info tf, 
        role_enabled f,
        role_def rd
                            WHERE
        tf.teacher_id = p.teacher_id
        AND st.teacher_id = p.teacher_id
        AND tf.teacher_id = f.link_id
        AND f.role_id = rd.role_id
        AND p.primary_college_id = st.college_id
        AND rd.role_id != 109 
        AND st.transferred = 'Y';

BEGIN
    FOR rec IN teacher_exist LOOP
        SELECT
            p.teacher_id
        INTO u_id
        FROM
            teacher p,
            teacher_info ps, 
            role_enabled f,
            role_def rd
        WHERE
            ps.teacher_id = p.teacher_id
            AND ps.teacher_id = f.link_id
            AND f.role_id = rd.role_id
            AND p.primary_college_id = rec.college_id
            AND rd.role_id = 109 
            AND p.teacher_status = 'A' 
            AND ROWNUM = 1;

        UPDATE student_info sf
            SET 
                sf.teacher_id = u_id
        WHERE
            sf.student_id = rec.student_id
            AND sf.college_id = rec.college_id;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an Oracle error message. What does it mean? Wou should debug that code in order to find it out.

Comment: I am running the code in sql developer and see that the records are not getting updated. So asked here!!

Comment: Who knows? Maybe cursor's SELECT returned nothing. Maybe SELECT INTO U_ID returned nothing. Maybe UPDATE's WHERE clause caused no rows to be updated. As I've said, you should debug it, make sure everything works out of PL/SQL, and then - once you're sure it is OK - move it back.

Comment: I have checked cursor's SELECT query returning one teacher_id. But the new teacher id is not getting updated.

Comment: OK, so UPDATE's WHERE clause prevents that to happen, which means that you'll have to fix it. Display (using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE) values of U_ID, REC.STUDENT_ID and REC_COLLEGE_ID and use them in UPDATE in SQL - doing so, you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Being able to ask a question that can be answered is a vital skill for anyone. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips for doing just that. Just listing your code and saying it doesn't work is no help for anyone - least of all you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no need for a loop or even PL/SQL for this. You should also learn how to use the modern explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)